# C++ Templates:-Warning in a function template

Tags: c++, templates

The following function templates attempt to calculate the max value out of the entered values. The FT is works just fine when I use it with a single data type but displays a warning when used with two different data types.

The function is as follows:

```
template<typename T,typename U>
const T& maxVal(const T& var1,const U& var2)
{
if(var1<var2)
    return var1;
else
    return var2;
}
```

and the user function ( main ) is as follows:-

```
int main(void)
{
  int var1 = 10;
  double var2 = 20.10;
  cout<<maxVal(10,20.10)<<endl;   // warning displayed " returning reference to temporary"
   cout<<maxVal(var1,var2)<<endl; // warning still persists in this case
  return 0;
}
```

When I remove `U` data type and replace it with `T`, then the program runs smoothly. Why is this happening?

Comment: use `std::max` instead

Comment: should be `template<typename T, typename U>`?

Comment: There can't be no warning because that template will not compile. Show real code, please.

Comment: What return type should it be if I say maxVal(std::string("foo"), -101.3)?

Comment: @doctorlove it will throw an error because one is char type and other is double and hence the function will face initialization as it will have to convert `const char[4]` to `const &char[4]`.

Comment: Right, but for a double and an int it can make a reference to the temporary int it decides to return, as the error says

Comment: @doctorlove can you tell me how to handle the code you gave ? I am unable to do it as char and int are very different and cannot be implicitly converted as `int` is converted to `double`.

Comment: max makes no sense for two very different data types. That's all I meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template<typename T>
const T& maxVal(const T& var1,const T& var2)
```

If you use `maxVal(10,20.10)` one will be implicitly casted to another. here double is getting casted to int

```
template<typename T,typename U>
const T& maxVal(const T& var1,const U& var2)
```

with this implementation, you are always returning `T` so if `var2` is max it is casted to `T`

Comment: The return type is incorrect, what is var2 is the max? The return type should be U (or a third type?).

Comment: you could use auto for the return type

Comment: that will be C++11 specific

Comment: If something is *user* defined then coercion rules has to be defined by user as well. you have to overload

Answer (score 1):

If T is an int and U is a double, then when U is the maximum value, you will be trying to return a double reference as an int reference. You can't do that, so the compiler will first perform a type conversion from double to int, resulting in a temporary variable, which it then returns as a reference that will promptly go out of scope as soon as the function returns.

If you changed it to return T instead of T& then it should work.

And by work, I mean that it will not give you a warning about a temporary variable. But I doubt it will do what you expect, either.

If your double is the maximum and is returned as an int, then you are not going to get back the same value that you put in. Instead you will get an int representing the rounded value of your double. In your example, it will output 20 instead of 20.10.

You would really need to use a macro to do what you seem to want to do in your example.

```
#define maxValue(a1,a2) \
   (a1 < a2 ? a2 : a1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may actually want something like this:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
auto maxVal(const T& var1, const U& var2) -> decltype(var1<var2?var2:var1)
{
    return var1<var2 ? var2:var1;
}
```

However, runtime variable cannot be deducted at compile time. Code like this can only work at compile time, since its return type must be ensure when compile.

**EDIT:**

To my surprise, this code actually works for GCC 4.8 even used for runtime variable. Hope anybody can explain this magic?

**EDIT2:**

Sorry, my bad. See comment below by @Sebastian Redl for explanation.

Comment: Types are a compile time property and independent of any runtime values. Did you think this function magically changes its return type to the type of the maximum? No, the compiler just deduces what type the expression has (the "common type" of `T` and `U`) and uses that.

Answer (score -1):

The warning "returning reference to temporary" refers to you returning a reference to an temporary variable (the one inside of your function, that goes off scope when the function terminates).

Why are you returning a const reference?

```
template<typename T,typename U>
const T maxVal(const T& var1,const U& var2)
{
if(var1<var2)
    return var1;
else
    return var2;
}
```

Comment: what is temporary here ?

Comment: The temporary is created when it performs a type conversion from U to T.

Comment: is it optional? I was told that if I return a reference, it'll save me creating a copy of the `<T>` type variable.

Comment: when `const T&` is implicitly converted to `const U&` why would it create temporary ?

Comment: Returning a reference(&) to var1/var2 can be implemented as a pointer. You are basically returning the address of a variable that might contain garbage. And yes, the type conversion creates a const temporary variable.

Comment: It will not implicitly convert const U& to const T& unless U is derived from T. With an int and a double it has to first convert U to T, creating a temporary variable, and then return a reference to the temporary T.

Comment: @Gerald it is also creating a temporary variable when I am converting int to double when I return a double reference. I don't think that this should happen because `int` is already a `double`, isn't it?

Comment: @kusur An int is not a double. Ints are ints and doubles are doubles.

Comment: No, int is not a double. An int can be implicitly converted to a double, but the compiler has to do some work for that. int and double are represented quite differently in memory, so they are not compatible without conversion.